# I am getting "ProgrammingError: Unknown character set: 'utf8mb4' " while using the code given below..Please suggest a solution

Tags: python, mysql

So initially I installed the mysql.connector in python through the pip command. The installation was successful.
But while trying out the given code:

```
import mysql.connector as sql
mycon=sql.connect(host="localhost",user="[name]",passwd="[pswd]",database="test")
if mycon.is_connected():
     print("Connected")
```

I got this error:

`ProgrammingError: Unknown character set: 'utf8mb4'`

I am using Spyder(3.7) and Mysql(5.1.33).
Please Help.

Comment: mysql 5.1 does not support utf8mb4.

Comment: Your mysql is way way way too old.

Comment: I realised that but is there anything I could do? That is other than installing a new version.

Comment: 5.1 has been unsupported since 2013.  upgrade to mysql 8 or mariadb 10.5

Comment: Thanks ..it worked

Answer (score 0):

The utf8mb4 character sets was added in MySQL 5.5. You need to `upgrade MySQL to version 5.5.3 or greater`.
You can also replace `utf8mb4 with utf8` in your SQL file if you don't want to upgrade SQL version.